# Updating a Whole Table (Laravel and Vuejs)

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a table on admin panel which contains 60 rows and 10 columns. Those columns belongs 2 different tables in database. Simplified version is like so:

---

### | Asset | Trade | Status | Code | Link |

Code and Link columns contain empty text inputs. When I enter anything, their values go to Vue.js object and I save them in the Posts table which works perfectly fine.

Trade and Status columns have radio buttons and they belong to Trades table. When I check the radio buttons, their values go to Vue.js object. When I try to update the Trades table it returns 405 error.

The button calls that function:

```
publish() {
  this.form.post("/api/posts")
    .then(() => {
      this.form
        .put("/api/trades")
    })
    .catch(() => {
      //error codes...
    });
}
```

I don't know if POST and PUT requests can be used together, or if this is the correct syntax, but I like to make both action with one click.

My update function is down below. As you can see I'm trying to use "asset_id" which is the foreign key in the Trades table, instead of "id" which is primary key of Trades table. I think this causes the problem, but I'm not sure. I also add that line of code to Post modal file, but it didn't help:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'asset_id';
```

My update function:

```
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $asset_id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $asset_id)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    if (count($input['asset_id']) > 0) {
        foreach ($input['asset_id'] as $asset_id) {
            if (array_key_exists($asset_id, $input['status'])) {
                $updates = [
                    'trade' => $input['trade'][$asset_id],
                    'status' => $input['status'][$asset_id],
                    'private' => (array_key_exists($asset_id, $input['public_code']) ? 0 : 1)
                ];
                Post::where('asset_id', $asset_id)->find($asset_id)->update($updates);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I check the radio buttons and fill the inputs Vue.js object becomes something like this:

```
form: new Form([
    asset_id: [2, 5, 16, 52],
    trade: {
      2: "Long",
      5: "None",
      16: "Long",
      52: "Short" 
    },
    status: {
      2: "Active",
      5: "Canceled",
      16: "Pending"
      52: "Active"
    },
    public_code: {
      2: "VBFABVR",
      16: "hmbtr46"
    },
    link: {
      2: "http://...",
      16: : "http://..."
    }
])
```

I'm not sure if I should provide more details. If it's so, please let me know. I hope someone tells me what is wrong here.

EDIT: 
Route codes:

```
Route::apiResources([
    'users' => 'API\UsersController',
    'roles' => 'API\RolesController',
    'plans' => 'API\PlansController',
    'categories' => 'API\CategoriesController',
    'assets' => 'API\AssetsController',
    'posts' => 'API\PostsController',
    'trades' => 'API\TradesController',
]);
```

Route List:

```
| POST      | api/trades         | trades.store   | App\Http\Controllers\API\TradesController@store   | api
| GET|HEAD  | api/trades         | trades.index   | App\Http\Controllers\API\TradesController@index   | api
| PUT|PATCH | api/trades/{trade} | trades.update  | App\Http\Controllers\API\TradesController@update  | api
| GET|HEAD  | api/trades/{trade} | trades.show    | App\Http\Controllers\API\TradesController@show    | api
| DELETE    | api/trades/{trade} | trades.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\API\TradesController@destroy | api
```

Comment: Can you add the route code for "/api/posts" and "/api/trades" to your question.

Comment: Hi. I did what you said. I also added the route list of trades. Update function's URI is api/trades/{trade} but I'm not passing a single trade. I'm passing a collection. Can it be the source of my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a rookie mistake. I was trying to pass a collection of the trades to database, but put request requires /api/trades/$id. That's why I've created a for loop in front-end, and in back-end, all I need was a simple update function.

This is the function that is called when I click the submit button:

```
publish() {
  var trades = this.form.asset_id.length;
  this.form.post("/api/posts")
  for (var i = 0; i < trades; i++) {
    if (this.form.asset_id[i] in this.form.status) {
        this.form.put("/api/trades/" + this.form.asset_id[i])
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the upload function:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $item = Trade::findOrFail($id);
    $input = $request->all();
    $updates = [
        'trade' => $input['trade'][$id],
        'status' => $input['status'][$id],
        'private' => (array_key_exists($id, $input['public_code']) ? 0 : 1)
    ];
    $item->update($updates);
}
```